# How to place multiple graphs in same coordinate system (pandas,mathplotlib) -> look pic

Tags: pandas, graphs, jupyter, matplotlib

[image]

in short how to set graphs in same coordinate system, not separated as in pic each in its own coordinate system in one frame....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the dtype of your y values. It's "object" and thus matplotlib thinks two object containing same float value are different.

Use,

```
y  = a.astype(float).values
y1 = b.astype(float).values
y2 = c.astype(float).values
```